# Failed to Change css class inside frameset Asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css, asp.net

I have an issue with frameset. I have a web application hosted in my site by a third party vendor.Unfortunately I don't have access to the code behind and I am trying to do it in .aspx page using Jquery.
 I need to change the classname of a 'td' with in a frame with in a frameset. I tried it like this

```
var doc = $("frame[name='frameTop']", top.document);
var _div = emrdoc.getElementById('elementID');
_div.className = "Newclassname";
```

Can anyone help me on this?
regards,
Sivajith

Answer (score 0):

```
$("frame[name='frameTop']", top.document).find('#elementId').attr('class', 'newClassName')
```